# Why my emulator isn't destroying activity in landscape mode?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-activity

My android emulator should destroy the contents of textView widget when I turn it to landscape from portrait. But it isn't doing that, WHY? Isn't it destroying the activity? 
look in the emulator "this is the first text"-- I added this line in emulator when it was in portrait mode.

````
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var textView: TextView? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        //comment
        val userInput: EditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
        val button: Button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
        textView?.text = ""
        textView?.movementMethod =
            ScrollingMovementMethod() // It allows my text view widget to scroll upward
        userInput.text.clear()

        button.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
                textView?.append(userInput.text)
                textView?.append("\n")
                userInput.setText("")
            }
        })
    }
}
```[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLRr3.png
````

Comment: `TextView`, as well as many other built-in widgets, overrides `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` and is therefore capable of restoring its state after your activity is recreated.

Comment: But the Instructor in an udemy course I am following did the same thing but his activity wasn't recreated and his contents in TextView widget disappeared.